# Cumsum for different variables for unique game_id in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe, containing game_ids, players, type of actions (e.g. a pass or a dribble) and whether the action resulted in a succes or a fail.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  game_id = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
              "2", "2", "2", "2", "2"),
  player  = c("X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z", "Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "Z",
              "Z", "X", "Z", "X"),
  type    = c("pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "dribble", "dribble", 'tackle', "pass",
              "pass", "dribble", "pass", "dribble", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "dribble", 
              "pass", "pass"),
  result  = c("success", "success", "fail", "success", "success", "success", "fail", "success",
              "fail", "success", "success", "fail", "fail", "success", "success", "fail", "fail",
              "success", "success", "success")
)

df1

#   game_id player    type  result
#1        1      X    pass success
#2        1      X    pass success
#3        1      X    pass    fail
#4        1      Y    pass success
#5        1      Y    pass success
#6        1      Z dribble success
#7        1      Z dribble    fail
#8        1      X  tackle success
#9        1      Y    pass    fail
#10       1      Z    pass success
#11       2      Y dribble success
#12       2      Y    pass    fail
#13       2      Y dribble    fail
#14       2      X    pass success
#15       2      X    pass success
#16       2      Z    pass    fail
#17       2      Z    pass    fail
#18       2      X dribble success
#19       2      Z    pass success
#20       2      X    pass success
```

What I would like to do is create a few new columns:

- The first column consists of each pass a player has given in a unique match (does not matter whether the pass failed or succeeded)
- the second column consists of each SUCCESS pass a player has given in a unique match
- The third column shows the success rate of each player during the game (thus successful passes given by player / total passes given by player)

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  game_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
  player  = c("X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z", "Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "Z",
              "Z", "X", "Z", "X"),
  type    = c("pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "dribble", "dribble", 'tackle', "pass",
              "pass","dribble", "pass", "dribble", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "dribble", 
              "pass", "pass"),
  result  = c("success", "success", "fail", "success", "success", "success", "fail", "success",
              "fail", "success", "success", "fail", "fail", "success", "success", "fail", "fail",
              "success", "success", "success"),
  pass_per_player = c(1,2,3,1,2,0,0,3,3,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,3), 
  success_pass_player = c(1,2,2,1,2,0,0,2,2,1,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,2,1,3),
  #success_rate_player = c(1,1,0.66,1,1,0,0,0.66,0.66,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0.33,1)
)

df2

#   game_id player    type  result pass_per_player success_pass_player success_rate_player
#1        1      X    pass success               1                   1                1.00
#2        1      X    pass success               2                   2                1.00
#3        1      X    pass    fail               3                   2                0.66
#4        1      Y    pass success               1                   1                1.00
#5        1      Y    pass success               2                   2                1.00
#6        1      Z dribble success               0                   0                0.00
#7        1      Z dribble    fail               0                   0                0.00
#8        1      X  tackle success               3                   2                0.66
#9        1      Y    pass    fail               3                   2                0.66
#10       1      Z    pass success               1                   1                1.00
#11       2      Y dribble success               0                   0                0.00
#12       2      Y    pass    fail               1                   0                0.00
#13       2      Y dribble    fail               1                   0                0.00
#14       2      X    pass success               1                   1                1.00
#15       2      X    pass success               2                   2                1.00
#16       2      Z    pass    fail               1                   0                0.00
#17       2      Z    pass    fail               2                   0                0.00
#18       2      X dribble success               2                   2                1.00
#19       2      Z    pass success               3                   1                0.33
#20       2      X    pass success               3                   3                1.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first start is this:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(game_id, player) %>%
  mutate(
    pass_per_player = cumsum(type=="pass"),
    success_pass_player = cumsum(result=="success" & type=="pass"),
    success_rate_player = success_pass_player / pass_per_player)
# A tibble: 20 x 7
# Groups:   game_id, player [6]
   game_id player type    result  pass_per_player success_pass_player success_rate_player
   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>             <int>               <int>               <dbl>
 1 1       X      pass    success               1                   1               1    
 2 1       X      pass    success               2                   2               1    
 3 1       X      pass    fail                  3                   2               0.667
 4 1       Y      pass    success               1                   1               1    
 5 1       Y      pass    success               2                   2               1    
 6 1       Z      dribble success               0                   0             NaN    
 7 1       Z      dribble fail                  0                   0             NaN    
 8 1       X      tackle  success               3                   2               0.667
 9 1       Y      pass    fail                  3                   2               0.667
10 1       Z      pass    success               1                   1               1    
11 2       Y      dribble success               0                   0             NaN    
12 2       Y      pass    fail                  1                   0               0    
13 2       Y      dribble fail                  1                   0               0    
14 2       X      pass    success               1                   1               1    
15 2       X      pass    success               2                   2               1    
16 2       Z      pass    fail                  1                   0               0    
17 2       Z      pass    fail                  2                   0               0    
18 2       X      dribble success               2                   2               1    
19 2       Z      pass    success               3                   1               0.333
20 2       X      pass    success               3                   3               1
```

If you want to transform `NaN`s into `0`:

```
df1$success_rate_player[is.nan(df1$success_rate_player)] <- 0
```

Comment: However, I believe the first cumsum isn't really working, as it increments every pass, and not the pass for each player

Comment: You have the same result in your desired outcome

Comment: The above code gives me a different output unfortunately. I now tried the following, which works:

Comment: `df1 <-
 ddply(df1, .(game_id, player), transform, pass_per_player = cumsum(type == "pass"))`